# How can I avoid making multiple get request in this Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, get

I am working on an e-commerce app in Angular 11.

I have a service that makes a `get` request and reads a JSON.

The purpose of this service is to *determine which product is promoted*.

The service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Campaign } from '../models/campaign';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PromoProductsService {

  public apiURL: string;
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.apiURL = `${apiURL}/promo-products`;
  }

  public getPromoData(){
    return this.http.get<Campaign>(`${this.apiURL}/campaign`);
  }
}
```

In the product card component I have:

```
public getPromoData() {
    this.PromoProductsService.getPromoData().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe(data => {
      this.campaignData = data;
      this.campaignProducts = this.campaignData.campaign.products;

      let promoProduct = this.campaignProducts.find((product:any) => { 
        return this.product.product_id == product.id;
      });

      if (promoProduct) {
        this.isCampaignProduct = true;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
    });
}
```

##### The problem

The code above checks, for every product card, if the product is in the array of promoted products.

The problem with this is that there is *a request for the array of promoted products for every product* on the page.

##### Question:

How can I make (and use) a *single request* for the array of promoted products?

Comment: you can have the request in the service and keep the products array in the service. then every time you call getPromoData check if the array has products and if yes return it. only if the array is empty then call the API

Comment: @MordyStern I can not do the check `return this.product.product_id == product.id` in the service, because `this.product.product_id` is part of the component, not the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should share the result of your HTTP request to all components who need it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Campaign } from '../models/campaign';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PromoProductsService {

  public apiURL: string;

  promo$: Observable<Campaign>;
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.apiURL = `${apiURL}/promo-products`;
    this.promo$ = this.http.get<Campaign>(`${this.apiURL}/campaign`).pipe(shareReplay());
  }
}
```

This observable can the be used by different components in order only perform one single HTTP call (on first subscription).

In your component you can adjust your code to do the following:

```
public getPromoData() { 
 this.PromoProductsService.promo$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe(data => {
      this.campaignData = data;
      this.campaignProducts = this.campaignData.campaign.products;

      let promoProduct = this.campaignProducts.find((product:any) => { 
        return this.product.product_id == product.id;
      });

      if (promoProduct) {
        this.isCampaignProduct = true;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: How do I call `promo$` _only once_ from a component, in `getPromoData()`?

Comment: You don't actually "call" `promo$`. You subscribe to it exactly like you did before. i added some code to my answer to also consider your provided component code.

Comment: I get a `Cannot find name 'data'` error in the component.

Comment: Where exactly does this error come from? It's kind of strange, since in my code a `data` variable is used once, which is self defined in the callback function of `subscribe` call, so this cannot not be an issue (can be named in a callback function whatever you like).

Comment: `promo$` is `undefined` in the component.

Comment: Well, you should use `promo$` as a property of your injected PromoProductsService. If it's `undefined`, why were you able to invoke `.getPromoData()`, which is also a property of this service, before?

Comment: How do I use `promo$` as a property of my injected PromoProductsService?

Comment: Adjusted my answer to match your code samples. Now you should be able to just copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches, just to name 2 I would recommend:

- make use of [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) rxjs operator
- Call the service from the parent, that holds all the products and provide the whole list to the child, so the child is pretty much dumb